# I want to Auto-Add text after a formula on Google Sheets

Tags: excel, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I found a formula to get the last name from a Name cell, but I want to add a specific text after the last name to make it a password and apply it automatically to the all cells, example:

[image]

Sheet URL:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XHoxD-hNmpUOMVm_u-cz-4ESrabodsrS0fIfaN-n4js/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google-Sheet has `REGEXTRACT()` function while excel desktop version don't have. You can use below function which will work both in `google-sheet` as well as in excel all version.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))& "@2021"
```

For excel use-

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))& "@2021"
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Harun24HR, thanks for your answer the formula works well. But I need to make it an array, can you help me to do that? please!

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B," .*")&"@2021"))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A; " ")@2021);;2)
```