# How to auto get and merge "First & Last" name and add "@domain.com" and lowercase the all letters?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to auto get First And Last name from Cell to another cell and lowercase all the letters, then I want add domain name provider `"@example.com"`, please check this image to see an example:

[image]

Sheet URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XHoxD-hNmpUOMVm_u-cz-4ESrabodsrS0fIfaN-n4js/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ",""))&"@example.com"
```

Comment: Yes, or to make this an array `=INDEX(IF(C2:C="","",LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C," ",""))&"@example.com"),)`

Comment: Thanks Foxfire And Burns And Burns for the formula it's works well. And thanks to you too JvdV for your suggest to make it array because I was need it too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an arrayformula instead that you don't need to drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C),LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C," ",""))&"@example.com",""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Marios for this formula, it's also works well!

Comment: @7amza glad it was helpful to you

Comment: I really appreciate that Marios, can you go to this question and help me with the to make the formula that I was marked as an answer and make it an array too please! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66325511